# How to get DocumentURL from supplied IP Address

Tags: c#, upnp

This question may need to be edited by me as I am not sure if I am phrasing this question correctly...

I have a c# app.

I use the manageduPnp library to get a list of devices on my network.

On each device 'discovered' I get a list of properties that I can view. So, for example, the following screenshot will show these properties:

[image: Breakpoint..]

Now, I am primarily concerned with the DocumentURL property as it will return an XML on all these properties for this device.

Is there a way when only the ip address is known to be able to know what the DocumentURL value is so then I can make a subsequent call to get more properties?

This would be done without using the upnp library.

Please note that by observation the DocumnetURL is not always called 'upnpdevicedesc.xml'

I stand ready to delete this question if it turns out to be a bad question...

Comment: There is no generic way to use only the IP address of a UPnP device to determine paths to any resource it serves.  UPnP control point stacks normally handle the details involved in invoking actions or reading state variables.  Why do you need to read properties from a UPnP device without using a UPnP stack?

Comment: @simonc Hi, thanks for commenting.  I am anticipating that the device is not discover-able or is prohibited by a firewall or/and on a different sub-net. I am working with digital cameras and they normally come pre-configured with a static ip address and different sub-net. I wanted to do a 1 stop setup to discover the camera. Detrmine what model and make it is and then hopefully find the rtsp connection string for it

Comment: Why exactly would a UPnP device be not discoverable? The reason you are not getting any answers is probably that the whole problem sounds so unrealistic: Why would anyone implement a UPnP device if it's not then discoverable as a UPnP device -- and are you sure some cameras actually do this?

Comment: Hi @jku thanks for taking the time to comment.  I agree this is probably an unrealistic scenario and I was curious about it.  Most cameras have on-board software and you can set it to be none discover-able if the User/manufacturer wishes.  Additionally, the camera may be pre-fixed to a different subnet and I believe then it would not be discover-able?